# Webdriver visibility of element without locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to check the text of my string(client) inside  tag using the following code:

```
boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
```

If it returns true then, Is there any way to directly check the visibility of this string (without locator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find an element that contains the needed text in its text node:

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + client + "']"));
   ```

   If needed, use `normalize-space()` or `contains()` instead:

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + client + "')]"));
   ```

   This will find the innermost element containing the text, not its any random ancestor.
2. Check whether it's visible via

   ```
   element.isDisplayed()
   ```

Note that you have to be sure your text only appears once on the page for this to be okay. But the solution can be easily adapted for more elements, too.

Comment: The above implementation works and fits your requirement, but please for the love of god don't do it!  If you don't know where the text is on your page and you are just going to randomly grab anything and say it's all good if it's visible your test is worthless anyway.

Comment: Exactly. What he said. The intent of front-end testing is to make sure everything appears where it should and when it should the way it should. You only test whether the page contains some text that could appear on the page for a different reason than you're expecting.